# Checking if CSV file is empty / avoiding having an exception be thrown

Tags: c#, winforms, csv, csvhelper

If I call `csv.Read()` on a CSV file that is completely empty, I get an exception. Is there a way to check the CSV without having to fall back on a Catch block?

```
var csv = new CsvReader(csvFile);

try
{
    while (csv.Read())
    {
        // process the CSV file...
    }
}
catch (CsvReaderException)
{
    // Handles this error (when attempting to call "csv.Read()" on a completely empty CSV):
    // An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.CsvReaderException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll
    // Additional information: No header record was found.
    MessageBox.Show(MessageBoxErrorMessageExpectedColumns, MessageBoxErrorMessageCaption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'd argue that this is a good time to use a try / catch...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply check if file has zero length

```
var csvFileLenth = new System.IO.FileInfo(path).Length;

if( csvFileLenth != 0)
{
  try
  {
    while (csv.Read())
    {
      // process the CSV file...
    }
  }
  catch (CsvReaderException)
  {
    // Handles this error (when attempting to call "csv.Read()" on a completely empty CSV):
    // An unhandled exception of type 'CsvHelper.CsvReaderException' occurred in CsvHelper.dll
    // Additional information: No header record was found.
    MessageBox.Show(MessageBoxErrorMessageExpectedColumns,              MessageBoxErrorMessageCaption, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use FileInfo

```
if (new FileInfo("yourfilename").Length == 0)
{
//Do something here
}
else
{
//Do something else here
}
```

You should also probably check to make sure the file exists because it will throw a FileNotFoundException if the file doesn't exist.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `File.Exists` on the source csvfile path.

```
if (File.Exists("csvfile"))
{
   //process
}
```

Edit: Apologies, misread your post, you would indeed need to combine this with the answer above to check for an empty (but existing) file.